# IPv6 address representation in Python

Tags: python, ipv6

I was converting IPv6 addresses to the textual representation and noticed a behavior I could not explain:

```
In[38]: socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET6, '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00\x01')
Out[38]: '::ffff:127.0.0.1'
In[39]: socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET6, '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00\x00')
Out[39]: '::ff:ffff:7f00:0'
```

I am surprised to see `::ffff:127.0.0.1`, I'd expect it to be `::ffff:7f00:0`. Is it standard or at least common? Which IPv6 addresses are represented this way? The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Presentation) doesn't mention it at all. I am confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [POSIX page for `inet_ntop`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/inet_ntop.html) specifies that format as one of the options (slightly paraphrased):

> A third form that is sometimes more convenient when dealing with a mixed environment of IPv4 and IPv6 nodes is `x:x:x:x:x:x:d.d.d.d`, where the `x` characters are the hexadecimal values of the six high-order 16-bit pieces of the address, and the `d` characters are the decimal values of the four low-order 8-bit pieces of the address (standard IPv4 representation).